# Google Charts chart area out of bounds

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I have a Google Charts annotation chart like the one below inside some tabs. The problem is, it's not being drawn properly as if it's a little out of bounds somehow.

I assume it's related to the chart being drawn when the page loads and then when I click on the tab, the size of the chart's container changes. But I'm not sure how to fix that. Any hint is greatly appreciated.

This is my chart:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', { 'packages': ['annotationchart'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Kepler-22b mission');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Kepler title');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Kepler text');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Gliese 163 mission');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Gliese title');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Gliese text');
    data.addRows([
        [
            new Date(2314, 2, 15), 12400, undefined, undefined,
            10645, undefined, undefined
        ],
        [
            new Date(2314, 2, 16), 24045, 'Lalibertines', 'First encounter',
            12374, undefined, undefined
        ],
        [
            new Date(2314, 2, 17), 35022, 'Lalibertines', 'They are very tall',
            15766, 'Gallantors', 'First Encounter'
        ],
        [
            new Date(2314, 2, 18), 12284, 'Lalibertines', 'Attack on our crew!',
            34334, 'Gallantors', 'Statement of shared principles'
        ],
        [
            new Date(2314, 2, 19), 8476, 'Lalibertines', 'Heavy casualties',
            66467, 'Gallantors', 'Mysteries revealed'
        ],
        [
            new Date(2314, 2, 20), 0, 'Lalibertines', 'All crew lost',
            79463, 'Gallantors', 'Omniscience achieved'
        ]
    ]);

    var options = {
        displayAnnotations: true,
        'height': 500,
        'width': 900,
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var chart2 = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
    var chart3 = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div3'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
    chart2.draw(data, options);
    chart3.draw(data, options);
}
```

And this is one of the tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li id="wellnav" class="@(item.Well == 1 ? "active" : "")"><a id="id2"
                                                                  href="#tab-@item.Well" 
                                                                  data-toggle="tab"">@item.Well</a></li>
}
```

```
<div id="tabs" class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-pane">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>       
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Here's an example on Fiddle on what I'm seeing. Notice how the chart in tab 2 has broken dimensions or, at least, doesn't look right. The fiddle is borrowed and modified from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445782/google-charts-with-tabs-chart-area-incorrect) post.

http://jsfiddle.net/06rwpft8/1/

Comment: jsFiddle would be useful

Comment: I've updated the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem the chart isn't rendered properly on hidden objects. Perhaps there are better ways to handle it directly in the google chart settings, but a solution would be to draw the actual chart when the tab is shown. For example, call the draw once if the tab is clicked:

```
$('a[title=content_2]').one('click',function(){
    chart2.draw(data, options);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/06rwpft8/2/)

Comment: Yes I've seen a few people having problems with google charts not rendering well on hidden objects and have had to 'hack' their way out of it. This seems to work for me for now, so thanks!